# Is "mas sin embargo" a pleonasm?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, adverbios

I've seen and heard "mas sin embargo". My questions are:

- Is it correct to use "mas sin embargo"?
- Is it a pleonasm?

Example:

> Mario tiene que hacer mucha tarea, mas sin embargo está jugando.
>
> Yo creo que es un pleonasmo, mas sin embargo hay veces que es usado.

Comment: Yes I think it's a pleonasm but the problem is not being or not beign a pleonasm but that it sounds strange and even artificial. Maybe it's a reginalism but I doubt you would ever hear a native (at least in Spain) using it.

Comment: @Laura I think the problem is that "mas" is less used than "pero". It's common to read things like "Mario tiene que hacer muchas tareas, **pero sin embargo** está jugando."

Comment: @Javi wouldn't be that a pleonasm too or is it used to make more emphasis?

Comment: @AlfredoO I think "pero sin embargo" is also a pleonasm. By the way, aren't pleonasms a way of emphasizing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's a pleonasm because both adverbs ("mas" and "sin embargo") has an **adversative meaning** and adding "**mas**" doesn't affect the meaning of the sentence. So it's redundant.

To me, these sentences have the same meaning though using "**mas sin embargo**" may make the sentence more **aesthetic for literature** (so it will probably be more used in writing than in speaking).

> Mario tiene que hacer muchas tareas, **sin embargo** está jugando.
>
> Mario tiene que hacer mucha tareas, **mas sin embargo** está jugando.

even they are quite close in meaning to:

> Mario tiene que hacer muchas tareas, **pero** está jugando.
>
> Mario tiene que hacer mucha tareas, **mas** está jugando. (this is very formal)